# Added a new method to a COM object that gets exception when called

Tags: c#, com

I have a method I have added to my COM class and everytime it gets called I get the following exception:

Exception : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE): The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
   at System.EnterpriseServices.IRemoteDispatch.RemoteDispatchNotAutoDone(String s)

There are other methods in this COM class that get called all the time with no problems. It only happens on my new method. Is there something special you need to do when adding new methods to COM objects? Let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the code from the method?

Comment: Does it use/expose any new types that weren't used by other methods?

Comment: I will try that John.

Damien: My COM method calls another method that has a new struct that it uses. Do I need to decorate that struct with something? I guess if I do John's suggestion and it works, it could mean that the struct is making it unhappy. Otherwise the code just uses standard .net simple objects.

Comment: John, removing the code from the method made it happy. Is it possible it is my custom struct object that I introduced?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you regenerate the COM interop wrapper after updating the COM object?

If I'm wrong on this clarification, please set me straight: I'm guessing you are referencing a COM lib from a managed C# lib?  When the ref is made, VS should generate an interop wrapper for you, but I'm not sure it will detect a change and regenerate the wrapper unless you manually re-reference your COM dll or regen the interop yourself.

Comment: Yes. I have two C# projects. One is the COM and one is the caller of the COM. I have re-added the COM project reference to the caller project again, no luck.